# HTML <A> tag not appearing on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Dataset with two DataTable. I want to show some fields of the DataTables in labels.

I am using Stored Procedure. 
Code is here------

```
private void GetInfoCompany()
        {
            int companyid;
            if (int.TryParse(hidCompanyId.Value, out companyid))
            {
                var ds = CompanyData.GetCompanyInfo(companyid);
                if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    var dtcontact = ds.Tables[0];
                    var dtprofile = ds.Tables[1];
                }
                if (dtcontact != null && dtcontact.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    lblContactName.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                    lblEmailId.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
                    lblPhoneNo.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["ContactNumber"].ToString();
                    lblState.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["State"].ToString();
                    lblCountry.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Country"].ToString();
                }
                if (dtprofile != null && dtprofile.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    lblCompanyName.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["CompanyName"].ToString();
                    lblWebsite.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Website"].ToString();
                    lblEmail.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
                    lblAltMail.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["AlternateEmail"].ToString();
                    lblCompanyAddress.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
                    lblPhNo.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Phone1"].ToString();
                    lblMobileNo.Text = dtcontact.Rows[0]["Mobile1"].ToString();


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide your master page code?

Comment: This part is correct. We need more code :)

Comment: Do you have a CSS class for `href` on your page?

Comment: Could be anything: textcolor==backgroundcolor, footer is hidden through css, something else is on top of your footer, etc. What if you add plain text to your footer, do you see that? Please extend your question.

Comment: Must be some other CSS class/id, because what you provided has no match in given table. Id's are different.

Comment: -1 we can't tell by your code any reference to the `<A>` tag you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

What css are you using for the footer table

```
.footerTable{background-color:#191919;width:100%;} //inline css
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0" class="footerTable">
 <tr> <td> <a href="#"> Link </a> </td> </tr> </table>
```

Comment: #footer_main_table
{
    font-family: "Geneva" , sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
 width: 1137px;
}

Answer (score 0):

You should look in firebug for the rendered output, hit F12.